# Excel2013 - Grabbing data from specific cells based on the selection from a drop down list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

Depending on the selection from a drop down list, I need to match data from a specific cell into another cell.  I have a list of Team Members and depending on which area they work in during a shift they will get an additional rate that is specific to each day and each choice. The sheet is for a full week but each day needs to be calculated.   My Drop down list applies to a row of Team Members and the Top cell is D10(Which contains my list from Sheet3; A1=A, A2=B, A3=C).  If Choice A is selected from the drop down list I need the exact data from G5 to show in F10; If choice B is selected, I need the exact data from G6 to show in F10; and if choice C is selected, I need the exact data from G7 to show in F10.  I have had success with one( *=CHOOSE($G$5,D10=Sheet3!A1,$G$5)* ) but cannot figure out how to write the multiple scenarios into one formula.  I am also wondering if I am going about this the wrong way.
Thanks in advance for your suggestions and help.
Carrie M.

Answer (score 0):

Please add a screen shot of your data, because your description is hard to follow. I'll update this answer to be more complete once you improve your question.

You can use the value from a drop-down list as the value for any of Excel's lookup functions.

In this example, cell C2 is a drop-down list, D2 is the (completely optional) column number to be used for the lookups. You can totally omit D2 and hard-code the column numbers into your lookups as we usually do, but I threw that in there to show the kind of flexibility that's possible.

I did get lazy, though, and hard-code it in for the index/match/match formula. Here are the formulas used:

> =VLOOKUP(C2,A8:C12,D2,FALSE)
>
> =INDEX(A8:C12,MATCH(C2,A8:A12,0),D2)
>
> =INDEX(A8:C12,MATCH(C2,A8:A12,0),MATCH("Data 1",A8:C8,0))

[image]